# VirtualBox "Bridged Adapter" network doesn't show up in VM

Tags: networking, centos, virtual-machine, virtualbox

Long story short, I'm trying to re-route information from an Android tablet into a CentOS VM on my Windows 7 host. I've set my Virtual Box manager to have two "Network" adapters (in Settings):

- Adapter 1 is attached to NAT and is enabled
- Adapter 2 is attached to Bridged Adapter (and the adapter type is Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop)

However, when I fire up my VM, running

```
/sbin/ifconfig
```

in bash only shows one ethernet connection (eth01) corresponding to the MAC address for Adapter 1. If I run:

`ifconfig -a` ,

an eth1 connection shows up with a MAC address matching my bridged adapter, but has no IP address.

I'm not entirely sure what to do - I've tried all promiscuous modes, and can't really seem to find anything on this specific problem online. From what I've found, most of these problems have come from the user using Wi-Fi, but I'm connected by ethernet cable.

For reference, here is my ifconfig -a:

```
eth0        Link encap: Ethernet  HWaddr 01:00:27:1D:C0:01
            inet addr: 10.0.2.15  Bcast: 10.0.2.255  Mask: 255.255.255.0
            UP BROADBAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU: 1500  Metric: 1
            RX packets: 35  errors: 0  dropped: 0  overruns: 0  frame: 0
            TX packets: 35  errors: 0  dropped: 0  overruns: 0  carrier: 0
            collisions: 0  txqueuelen:  1000
            RX bytes: 5305 (5.1 KiB) TX bytes: 3506 (3.4 KiB)

eth1        Link encap: Ethernet  HWaddr 01:00:27:39:AE:8F
            BROADBAST MULTICAST  MTU: 1500  Metric: 1
            RX packets: 0  errors: 0  dropped: 0  overruns: 0  frame: 0
            TX packets: 0  errors: 0  dropped: 0  overruns: 0  carrier: 0
            collisions: 0  txqeuelen: 1000
            RX bytes: 0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes: 0 (0.0 b)
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question is off-topic on Stack Overflow, please try http://superuser.com or http://serverfault.com instead.

Answer (score 1):

On my Debian bridged connection don't get addresses automatically and that's probably because the NetworkManager Applet (basic network manager in Debian) can't handle them. To be honest I don't know why.

To manually get proper IP address from DHCP you can run `dhclient`:

```
dhclient eth0
```